# debian hang on startup "starting the winbind daemon: winbind"

Tags: debian, winbind

I took a copy of a VM running a debian, just so that I can play around with it. I spin up the copy, but didn't give it any network connection to avoid conflict with the original one. However, when I turn the VM on, it seems to freeze after this startup message

```
Starting Sambe daemons:nmbd smbd
Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server: main    
Starting the Winbind daemon: winbind
```

how do i fix this? I never get to the prompt to login. This vm does have a mount point that connects to a windows share folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some processes don't handle it well when they're started up without valid network connectivity.

Your best bet would be to boot the VM into single-user mode (you don't mention what VM system you're using, but if you can get to the GRUB Linux kernel boot menu, edit the `kernel` line to add the word `single` at the end).  In single-user mode, the OS won't start up any services or applications.  You can then go in and disable `winbind` (and any other services you might need to turn off).

On Debian, the easiest way to do this would probably be:

```
sudo update-rc.d winbind disable
```

Or, you can do it manually with something like:

```
sudo rm /etc/rc3.d/S??winbind
```

After making that change, exit out to let your VM finish booting.  After it's booted up, and you have a valid working network config in place, you can start winbind again with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/winbind start
```